# Bukkit teleport - nullPointerException

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to teleport a user to their own realm using the following code:

```
@EventHandler
public static void onPortalTravel(PlayerPortalEvent event) throws Exception {
    if(event.getCause() == PlayerPortalEvent.TeleportCause.END_PORTAL) {
        int x = event.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockX();
        int y = event.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockY();
        int z = event.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockZ();

        String[] data = getPageData("http://example.com/game.php?type=getRealm&location="+x+":"+y+":"+z ).split(":"); // THIS RETURNS <username>:<oldblockid>

        String realm = data[0];
        int oldID = Integer.parseInt(data[1].trim());

        Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").getBlockAt(x, y, z).setTypeId(oldID);
 *err*  event.getPlayer().teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("realms/" + realm), 1, 65, 16.5));
    }

}
```

and the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.entity.CraftPlayer.teleport(CraftPlayer.java:395)
  at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2_entity.CraftEntity.teleport(CraftEntity.java:199)
  at com.mysite.plugin.Start.onPortalTravel(Start.java:202)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:425)
     ... 26 more
```

Comment: Do you have the Bukkit source to see what's going on on line 395 of CraftPlayer?

Comment: yea I do, I will take a look

Comment: the line at CraftPlayer.java:395 = WorldServer toWorld = ((CraftWorld) to.getWorld()).getHandle();
***
the line at CraftEntity.java:199 = return teleport(location, TeleportCause.PLUGIN);

Comment: Have you checked that `Bukkit.getWorld` in your own code hasn't returned null?

Comment: yep it's returning null :/

Comment: Okay, so that's what you need to focus on. Check whether `realm` is actually what you expect, for example.

Comment: System.out.println(Bukkit.getWorld("realms/" + realm) + ", " + realm); returns "null, MRVDOG", so realm is returning what it's supposed to, and world "realms/MRVDOG" exists, so I don't know what else to do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35372/discussion-between-mrvdog-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: The dudes here won't know as much as the people at http://forums.bukkit.org/forums/plugin-development.5/
Try asking there.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this world is not loaded yet. You have to load it first.

This snippets checks if the world is null. If it is null, it loads(if the world already exists)
or creates(if the world doesn't exist yet) the world.

```
@EventHandler
public static void onPortalTravel(PlayerPortalEvent event) throws Exception {
    if (event.getCause() == PlayerPortalEvent.TeleportCause.END_PORTAL) {
        int x = event.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockX();
        int y = event.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockY();
        int z = event.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockZ();

        String[] data = getPageData("http://example.com/game.php?type=getRealm&location="+x+":"+y+":"+z).split(":"); // THIS RETURNS <username>:<oldblockid>
        String realm = data[0];
        int oldID = Integer.parseInt(data[1].trim());

        Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").getBlockAt(x, y, z).setTypeId(oldID);
        World world = Bukkit.getWorld("realms/" + realm);
        if(world == null){
            //Loads a world with the name given in the constructor
            WorldCreator wc = new WorldCreator("realms/" + realm);
            world = Bukkit.createWorld(wc);

        }
        event.getPlayer().teleport(new Location(world, 1, 65,16.5));
    }

}
```