# Bukkit: Player.teleport() throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bukkit

I am making a `setspawn` and `spawn` command but "`/spawn`" does not work. I am using Bukkit 1.8.3. Anyone know why? here is the full code:

## Relevant Code

### /setspawn

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")) {
    if (!sender.hasPermission("setspawn")) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
        return true;
    }

    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot set spawn!");
        return true;
    }

    if (sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getWorld());
        getConfig().set("spawn.x", player.getLocation().getX());
        getConfig().set("spawn.y", player.getLocation().getY());
        getConfig().set("spawn.z", player.getLocation().getZ());
        saveConfig();
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Spawn has been set!");

        return true;
    }
}
```

### /spawn

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")) {
    if (!sender.hasPermission("spawn")) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
        return true;
    }

    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot teleport to spawn!");
        return true;
    }

    if (getConfig().getConfigurationSection("spawn") == null) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Spawn is not set!");
        return true;
    }

    if (sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(getConfig().getString("spawn.world"));
        double x = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.x");
        double y = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.y");
        double z = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.z");

        player.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

## Full Code

```
package me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack;

import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.EconomyResponse;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.PlayerInventory;
import org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredServiceProvider;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class System extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public static Economy econ = null;

    public void onEnable() {
        if (!setupEconomy()) {
            getLogger().severe(String.format("[%s] - Disabled because vault was not found!", getDescription().getName()));
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
            return;
        }

        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been actived!");
    }

    private boolean setupEconomy() {
        if (getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Vault") == null) {
            return false;
        }

        RegisteredServiceProvider < Economy > rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Economy.class);

        if (rsp == null) {
            return false;
        }

        econ = rsp.getProvider();
        return econ != null;
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been disabled! This will give big problems to server.");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent joinevent) {
        Player getplayer = joinevent.getPlayer();

        getplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Hey " + getplayer.getName() + "! Welcome to the Ultimate Prison server!");

        if (getplayer.getName().equals("Herobrine112211")) {
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.GOLD + "Server Creator Herobrine112211 has joined the game!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("contactowner")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("contactowner")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Console will never need owner support.");
                return true;
            }

            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Owner: Herobrine112211. Live chat skype: gangsteris33.");
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("reloadconfig")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("config.reload")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            reloadConfig();
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config reloaded successfully.");
            return true;
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("saveconfig")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("config.save")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            reloadConfig();
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config saved successfully.");
            return true;
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakeop")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.op")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                return true;
            }

            Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

            if (target == null) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                return true;
            }

            target.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You are now op!");
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakejoin")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.join")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a name!");
                return true;
            }

            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + args[0] + " joined the game.");
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("broadcast")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("broadcast")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please give a message to broadcast!");
                return true;
            }

            StringBuilder strbl = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                strbl.append(args[i] + " ");
            }

            String broadcastas = strbl.toString();
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.RED + broadcastas);
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("heal")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

                if (target == null) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                    return true;
                }

                target.setHealth(20);
                target.setFireTicks(0);
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " healed you!");
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");

                return true;
            }
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.setHealth(20);
                    player.setFireTicks(0);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your health is now full!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

                if (target == null) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player player = (Player) sender;
                target.setHealth(20);
                target.setFireTicks(0);
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " healed you!");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");
            }
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("feed")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("feed")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

                if (target == null) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");
                    return true;
                }

                target.setHealth(20);
                target.setFireTicks(0);
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " fed you!");
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");

                return true;
            }

            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.setFoodLevel(20);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your hunger is now full!");

                    return true;
                }

                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

                if (target == null) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");

                    return true;
                }

                Player player = (Player) sender;

                target.setFoodLevel(20);
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " fed you!");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");
            }
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tpall")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("teleport")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Cannot teleport everyone to console!");
                return true;
            }

            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    for (Player allplayers: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        World w = player.getLocation().getWorld();
                        double x = player.getLocation().getX();
                        double y = player.getLocation().getY();
                        double z = player.getLocation().getZ();

                        allplayers.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "All players teleported to you!");

                        return true;
                    }
                }

                for (Player allplayers: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

                    if (target == null) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                        return true;
                    }

                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    World w = target.getLocation().getWorld();
                    double x = target.getLocation().getX();
                    double y = target.getLocation().getY();
                    double z = target.getLocation().getZ();

                    allplayers.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "All players teleported to player!");

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("setspawn")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot set spawn!");
                return true;
            }

            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;

                getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getWorld());
                getConfig().set("spawn.x", player.getLocation().getX());
                getConfig().set("spawn.y", player.getLocation().getY());
                getConfig().set("spawn.z", player.getLocation().getZ());
                saveConfig();
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Spawn has been set!");

                return true;
            }
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("spawn")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot teleport to spawn!");
                return true;
            }

            if (getConfig().getConfigurationSection("spawn") == null) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Spawn is not set!");
                return true;
            }

            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(getConfig().getString("spawn.world"));
                double x = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.x");
                double y = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.y");
                double z = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.z");

                player.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));

                return true;
            }
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kit")) {
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot get kits!" + ChatColor.RED + "Kits:" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Starter");
                return true;
            }

            if (!sender.hasPermission("kit")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                return true;
            }

            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Kits:" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Starter");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("starter")) {
                    if (!sender.hasPermission("kit.starter")) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (sender instanceof Player) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        PlayerInventory pinv = player.getInventory();
                        EconomyResponse withdraw = econ.withdrawPlayer(player.getName(), 10);

                         if (withdraw.transactionSuccess()) {
                            pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_PICKAXE, 1));
                            pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD, 1));
                            pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_AXE, 1));
                            pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 20));
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You dont have required money ammount. Kit purchase failed!");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Kit was not found. Do /kit for kits.");

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

### Error Log

```
8:54:05 AM [ERROR] null
8:54:05 AM org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'spawn' in plugin UltimateCommandPack v1.0.0
8:54:05 AM at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:625) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1077) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:937) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:37) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:9) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
8:54:05 AM at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:60) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:670) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.DedicatedServer.A(DedicatedServer.java:336) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.z(MinecraftServer.java:626) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:534) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
8:54:05 AM Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
8:54:05 AM at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R2.entity.CraftPlayer.teleport(CraftPlayer.java:464) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R2.entity.CraftEntity.teleport(CraftEntity.java:223) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM at me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack.System.onCommand(System.java:313) ~[?:?]
8:54:05 AM at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
8:54:05 AM ... 15 more
```

I have no idea why it does not work. It looks like it should work. If you know the fix show me the solution. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `player.teleport()` may not be thread-safe in your `/spawn` logic? Could [this (*Null Pointer Teleport on Join*)](https://bukkit.org/threads/unsquashable-null-pointer-teleport-on-join.195484/) help you? Line 313, as shown in your error log, is this line: "**`player.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));`**"

Comment: I have a feeling that the World has not completely loaded, so check the values of `x`, `y`, and `z`. This question may also be helpful: [*(Stack Overflow) Bukkit teleport - nullPointerException*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212244/bukkit-teleport-nullpointerexception)

Comment: I added a TL;DR section above your full code and also re-titled your question, based on the output in your error log. Please read your error log carefully and start from the bottom and work your way to the top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of your `spawn.world` property in your config. If the world does not exists then the value of `w` will be `null`.

```
String worldName = getConfig().getString("spawn.world");
System.out.println(worldName); // Check if value is correct.
World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(worldName);
```

### Edit

In your `/setspawn` command, you are incorrectly setting your `spawn.world` configuration value.

As you have explained in your comment below, your `spawn.world` config property is being set to:

```
spawn.world=CraftWorld{name=world}
```

When it should actually be:

```
spawn.world=world
```

This is because [`Location.getWorld()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Location.html#getWorld()) returns a [`World`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/World.html) (`Object`) and not the name of the world (`String`). Instead of the `name` of the world, you are retrieving the `toString()` representation as I mentioned.

The [`World.getName()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/World.html#getName()) method returns the unique name of the world.

#### Change that

```
getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getWorld());
```

#### To this

```
getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
```

The [`getConfig().set(String,Object)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#set(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method takes an object as its second parameter and since you are passing an `Object` (`World`) to be written to a file, said `Object`'s `toString()` will be implicitly called.

---

### Notes

*The following notes were gathered during my initial investigation of your problem before more information was introduced.*

In the following post, user [blackwolf12333](https://bukkit.org/members/blackwolf12333.90618944/) had to make sure to remove new-line characters from the retrieved world name. More information can be found here:

[*{{bukkit.org}} [Solved] Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(worldname) returns null?*](https://bukkit.org/threads/bukkit-getserver-getworld-worldname-returns-null.85660/)

Additionally, as mentioned in my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495935/bukkit-player-teleport-throws-a-nullpointerexception/29497063#comment47151764_29495935) of your question [`Server.getWorld(String)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Server.html#getWorld(java.lang.String)) is not thread-safe. Be aware of this.

Comment: Ok this is what i got. I did the check worldname as a command when i set spawn it give me this: CraftWorld{name=world} soo the world is correct? then why its giving me the error? i tried adding the new world w = Bukkit.ge... replacing old one in spawn command. Same error.

Comment: Wait, the value of `worldName` was *"CraftWorld{name=world}"*? That is not a string, that is a string representation of an object.

Comment: Yes. That was the worldName. If this is wrong how do i fix it.

Comment: @Reaper123: OK, instead of setting your `spawn.world` config to be the `World.toString()`, set it to be `World.getName()`.

Comment: Yup that solved the problem now the checkworld is world. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) because you're storing the value `world.toString()` as the world name, instead of `world.getName()`:

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")) {
  if (sender instanceof Player) {
    Player player = (Player) sender;

    getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getWorld());
```

A [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown when:

> - <sub>Calling the instance method of a null object.</sub>
> - **Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.**
> - <sub>Taking the length of null as if it were an array.</sub>
> - <sub>Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.</sub>
> - <sub>Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.</sub>
>
> <sub><sub>(emphasis mine, from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html))</sub></sub>

When trying to get the `World` from the config, a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown because the world that you stored with `world.toString()` is not a valid world name, and therefor is not the name of any world.

The `String` returned by `world.toString()` is `CraftWorld{name=myWorldName}`, which is not the name of the world, the name of the world is `myWorldName` (in this example). If you want to fix this, you need to use `world.getName()`, which will return the correct value of `myWorldName`.

So, your `/setspawn` code should look something like this:

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")) {
  //your code...
  if (sender instanceof Player) {
    Player player = (Player) sender;

    getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getName());
    //the rest of your code
  }
  //the rest of your code
  return true;
}
```