# Setting the entire row of a two dimensional array at once

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I am attempting to set the entire row of a two dimensional array at once. What I have done is:

```
private char[][] defaultRotors = new char[8][26];
```

Which of course creates a two dimensional array of characters. I already have several lists of pre-determined characters, basically old arrays, that I would like to set to a column at once.

I.E., I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x<defaultRotors.length; x++){
    switch (x) {
        case 0:
            defaultRotors[x] =  {'E', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'L', 'G', 'D', 'Q', 'V', 'Z', 'N', 'T', 'O', 'W', 'Y', 'H', 'X', 'U', 'S', 'P', 'A', 'I', 'B', 'R', 'C', 'J'}; //the rotor
            break;
       ...
       the other seven rows, each a pre-determined set of characters
       ...
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to assign an entire row in that way outside of initialization?

Comment: `defaultRotors[x] =  new char[] {'E', ...};`.

Comment: `defaultRotors[x] = oldArray.clone()`

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have known that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832880/initialize-2d-array)