# Can I create a multidimensional array using single arrays to fill?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I had two randomly generated arrays (rows and columns) and I want them to be used to fill a multidimensional array. With the arrays being rows and columns, the multidimensional array would be matrix[rows][columns]. Just an example of how I generated rows:

```
int[] rows = new int[20];         
for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
rows[i] = (int)(Math.random()*1000 + 1);
    }
System.out.println("Rows Generated: " + Arrays.toString(randomArrayN));
  }
}
```

The columns array was also built this way. Is there an easy way to create a two-dimension array and use these arrays to fill them? 
I know this syntax is wrong but basically I want to know if there is a way to do this:

```
int matrix[][] = new int[rows][columns];
```

Comment: What is the randomArrayN in your first snippet?

Comment: _How_ exactly should the matrix be filled from your rows and columns array? Considering you would have n rows and m columns you have n + m values, but the matrix size is n * m.

Comment: If you try and add rows and columns at the same time to a 2d array, it would result in many conflicts ... so it depends on how you want to construct the multi-dimensional array as @Glains has pointed out

Comment: whoops, dont mind the randomArrayN, it was meant to be rows. I had changed the name of the array from that to rows. As for @Glains , the reality likely is that it is just more simple to create the values of rows and columns within the two-dimensional array rather than try to fill it with arrays already made, then?

Comment: As explained above, consider you have `rows = {1, 2, 3}` and `columns = {3, 4, 6}`. If you got `matrix = [rows.length][columns.length]` you have only __6__ values, but the matrix has a size of 3 * 3 = __9__. How do you want to calculate the values from your rows and column?

Answer (score 0):

Yea you definitely can, though it may be a bit more confusing.

You can initalize the 3d array with this:

```
// test is a 3d array
int[][][] test = {
          {
           {1, -2, 3}, 
           {2, 3, 4}
          }, 
          { 
           {-4, -5, 6, 9}, 
           {1}, 
           {2, 3}
          } 
};
```

I like to think this in terms or 3d obects, like a regtangluar prism. Each row (height)on the prism hold 2 things Length and Width, or a x,y. in other worlds you have a 2d array, one value is the column, the other is the row, in an array making it 3d.

[image]

now what if you want to print out values of the 3d array?
simply do this :

```
 for (int[][] array2D: test) {
    for (int[] array1D: array2D) {
       for(int item: array1D) {
          System.out.println(item);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's convenient to think of a 2-dimensional array in terms of rows and columns, a 2-dimensional array is just an array of arrays.

For example,

```
    int[] values1 = {1, 2 ,3};
    int[][] matrix1 = {values1, values1, values1};

    matrix1[1][1] = 42;
    System.out.println(matrix1[0][1]);
    System.out.println(matrix1[1][1]);
    System.out.println(matrix1[2][1]);
```

or

```
    int[] values2 = {1, 2 ,3};
    int[][] matrix2 = new int[3][3];
    matrix2[0] = values2;
    matrix2[1] = values2;
    matrix2[2] = values2;

    matrix2[1][1] = 42;
    System.out.println(matrix2[0][1]);
    System.out.println(matrix2[1][1]);
    System.out.println(matrix2[2][1]);
```

Note that in both cases a values array is used multiple times to initialize each *row* of the matrix.  So any change to any matrix element is reflected in the other *rows* (since each *row* is actually the same array).  There may be cases where this is useful.  If the elements need to be independent then use something like this:

```
    int[] values3 = {1, 2 ,3};
    int[][] matrix3 = new int[3][3];
    System.arraycopy(values3, 0, matrix3[0], 0, values3.length);
    System.arraycopy(values3, 0, matrix3[1], 0, values3.length);
    System.arraycopy(values3, 0, matrix3[2], 0, values3.length);

    matrix3[1][1] = 42;
    System.out.println(matrix3[0][1]);
    System.out.println(matrix3[1][1]);
    System.out.println(matrix3[2][1]);
```

Each *row* of the matrix is initialized with a copy of the same value, but making changes to any element is independent of any other element (since it's a different array).

Also see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832880/initialize-2d-array) if the matrix needs to be initialized element by element.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 2d array filled with random ints, you can use a nested loop similar to what you used to genrate your rows above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matrix[][] = new int[20][20];
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*1000 + 1);
        }
    }

    for(int[] row : matrix){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }        
}
```