# How to change from user input of adjacency matrix into hard coding it into the program?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, dijkstra, adjacency-matrix

```
try
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number of vertices");
    number_of_vertices = scan.nextInt();
    adjacency_matrix = new int[number_of_vertices + 1][number_of_vertices + 1];
 
    System.out.println("Enter the Weighted Matrix for the graph");
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_vertices; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_vertices; j++)
        {
            adjacency_matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            if (i == j)
            {
                adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 0)
            {
                adjacency_matrix[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what the user input looks like:

```
Enter the number of vertices
5
Enter the Weighted Matrix for the graph
0 9 6 5 3 
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 4 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

How would I be able to hard code the matrix into the program rather than ask the user to enter the matrix?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832880/initialize-2d-array

Comment: Use "something different" instead of `System.in`..?